# How to cancel incoming request in .net core 6 API?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

In .NET core 6 API application. I would like to cancel the incoming request if it's take more than x minutes to complete the call in service layer and return with 504 status code.  In my service layer all i have is regular async method that make a call to active directory lookup.

I am using IIS to host this API. I have try settings in IIS itself but no luck.

There is attribute called [`requestTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attributes-of-the-aspnetcore-element:%7E:text=0%0AMax%3A%20100-,requestTimeout,-Optional%20timespan%20attribute) in web.config but it doesn't work with in-process hosting.

Comment: Have your tried `builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(c =>{c.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);});`?

Comment: @Rena,  Kestrel considered as out-process hosting. I am using IIS in-process hosting. I still apply those changes but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure an endpoint to timeout by calling WithRequestTimeout, or by applying the [RequestTimeout] attribute

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Timeouts;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRequestTimeouts();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRequestTimeouts();

app.MapGet("/", async (HttpContext context) => {
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), context.RequestAborted);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        return Results.Content("Timeout!", "text/plain");
    }

    return Results.Content("No timeout!", "text/plain");
}).WithRequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
// Returns "Timeout!"

app.MapGet("/attribute",
[RequestTimeout(milliseconds: 2000)] async (HttpContext context) => {
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), context.RequestAborted);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        return Results.Content("Timeout!", "text/plain");
    }

    return Results.Content("No timeout!", "text/plain");
    });
// Returns "Timeout!"

app.Run();
```

For apps with controllers, apply the `[RequestTimeout]` attribute to the action method or the controller class. For Razor Pages apps, apply the attribute to the Razor page class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/timeouts?view=aspnetcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I came across this article and `RequestTimeout` introduce in .net core 8.  Even thought if i upgrade my app to .net core 8, I am not using `Delay()` or `HttpClient` where I can send token and it raise the token cancellation after certain seconds. In my code I am updating group in active directory and it doesn't take cancellation token.

Answer (score 0):

If your API method is async, use the cancellation token to cancel it.

cancellati0nTokenInstance.CancelAfter(3500);

Comment: In order to `CancelAfter` trigger you need to cancel the token. I am not using Delay or HttpClient async method. I know i can not use `Task.Run()` due to performance issue.